# How does webpack resolves code to include in bundle

Tags: webpack

I'm wondering about how webpack selects code to include in the bundles.

Does it includes full .js files or only necessary code?

When working with external libraries (like jQuery). Does it include the full bundle or only the necessary functions?

**How does webpack resolves which code should be in the final bundle?**

Answer (score 0):

> Does it includes full .js files or only necessary code ?

This depends if you are bundling your third party code with webpack. **If you are simply loading in a static asset from an external api such as jQuery then it is not being bundled and Webpack won't know anything about it.**

However if the third party code for example Jquery lives within the dependency chain of the files that you are bundling with Webpack then all the jQuery code that is imported by other modules would be bundled together with the rest of the modules with Webpack. **The result of the bundling process is one big file comprised of all the modules** including any third party modules that are depended upon.

> When working with external libraries (like jQuery). Does it include
>   the full bundle or only the necessary functions ?

**Module / Dependency resolution in Webpack**

By mapping out a graph of the dependencies Webpack is able to load the different modules in the correct order asynchronously. Internally Webpack has its own resolver for figuring out the depedency graph between different modules. The webpack docs state that

The resolver helps webpack finds the module code that needs to be included in the bundle for every such require/import statement.
Then the docs explain that the resolver takes a different approach according to the type of path that is referenced by imports in the files that Webpack is bundling.

> The resolving process is pretty simple and distinguishes between three
>   types of requests:
>
> - absolute path: require("/home/me/file"), require("C:\Home\me\file")
> - relative path: require("../src/file"), require("./file") module path:
> - require("module"), require("module/lib/file")

For more info on how Webpack resolves modules see [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).